# php define constant - scope of use?

Tags: php, scope, global-variables, constants

Not wanting this question to be too long, I will skip to an example:
If I have 2 files: paper.php and rock.php, and they contain the following:

**paper.php:**

```
include('rock.php');
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die("Couldn't select database");
```

and **rock.php:**

```
define ("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define ("DB_USER", "foo");
define ("DB_PASS","bar");
define ("DB_NAME","fooDBar");
```

Eventually, will the user viewing my paper.php file be connected to the DB or not?

Comment: It should work as you've coded.

Comment: a DIY test-approach would have been much quicker than posting it here, by the way :) Yup, i often use an include-file with tons of constants like in your example, works like a charm

Comment: thanks everyone! a test would have been faster of course,but my server has some issues right now so yeah... i posted here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you define all the appropriate variables in `rock.php` and are including `rock.php`, then they will be defined for the whole program execution, including where you do a `mysql_connect()`.

Answer (score 12):

Not wanting the answer to be too long:

Yes.